# Sharing EFS with Samba - missing files

Tags: samba, amazon-efs

I'm trying to share AWS EFS content using Samba (to use it on Windows based instances). The issue is that with some number of files per folder, Samba doesn't show all of them. I tried different linux distros and also dockerized Samba version. Here's a way to reproduce the issue:

1. Mount EFS:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /efs
sudo mount -t nfs4 fs-xxx.efs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:/ /efs
```

2. Create 1K empty files there:

```bash
sudo mkdir /efs/1k
for i in {1..1000}; do sudo touch /efs/1k/$i; done
```

2. Create a Samba share:

```bash
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[efs]
path = /efs
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

3. Mount the share locally:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /samba
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //localhost/efs /samba
```

4. Count files on EFS and the same files exposed by Samba

```bash
$ find /efs/1k -type f | wc -l
1000
$ find /samba/1k -type f | wc -l
172
```

Comment: I've just tried it on the last AWS linux (2023) and found the issue is still there